# Way to find most people connected on OpenVpn?

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn

So I know that if you set up telnet and then type in 'load-stats' OpenVpn will tell you how many clients are connected at the moment, but is there a way to find the highest amount of people that have ever connected to your server? (a sort of connection record?)

Apologies if this question has an easy/obvious response but I've just set up an OpenVpn server and I'm quite new to everything :)

Answer (score 1):

OpenVPN has no such functionality you're looking for, but please take a look at pfsense:

[image: pfsense-example]

You could analyze PHP code in pfsense and create something similar using RRDtool like they did.